# How do i `\tag` a subequations environment as a whole?

Tags: cross-referencing, numbering, subequations

I have a similar subequations environment as in the mwe

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
  \begin{subequations}\label{eq:w} %\tag{myEQ}
  \begin{align}
    a &= b \label{eq:s1} \tag{myEQ.1}\\ %\tag{\ref{eq:w} 1}
    c &= d \label{eq:s2} \tag{myEQ.2}   %\tag{\ref{eq:w} 2}
  \end{align}
  \end{subequations}
   I need to reference \eqref{eq:w} and \eqref{eq:s1} and 
   would like the tags to be coherent 

\end{document}
```

I found [this related question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/161537/23166) where the numbering within 
the subequation is automated. However, that is not my concern, 
rather then the fact that `\eqref{eq:w}` should show *(myEQ)* rather than *(1)*.

Comment: Will all subequations in your document have the prefix "myEQ"?

Comment: Since LaTeX is linear and `subequations` just change the counter, how should `eq:q` know that you are using `\tag`, you'd probably need to make your own version of `subequations` that allows the user to add a prefix to the autogenerated equation numbers, and then *not* use `\tag`

Comment: @daleif , the \tag in subequations was meant to suggest the functionality i needed, rather than syntax. `\def\@currentlabel{myEQ}` in the accepted answer is the way to achieve the functionality...

Comment: @LaRiFaRi , the setting is a long document in which a model is presented at the beginning and then may be referred to (partially or as a whole) much later on. naming the model is intended to avoid scrolling/turning back to the first pages each time. thus, it will be this particular system of equation to need the personalised tag.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If only once, please do

```
% arara: pdflatex
% arara: pdflatex

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}
    \begin{subequations}
        \makeatletter
        \def\@currentlabel{myEQ}
        \makeatother
        \label{eq:w}
        \renewcommand{\theequation}{myEQ.\arabic{equation}}
        \begin{align}
            a &= b \label{eq:s1}\\
            c &= d \label{eq:s2}
        \end{align}
    \end{subequations}
    I need to reference \eqref{eq:w} and \eqref{eq:s1} and 
    would like the tags to be coherent. 
\end{document}
```

[image]

If you need it more often, you should take a look on [numbering parentequation of subequations](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/187372)

I do not get your last point. The equations are aligned. In your MWE already.

Comment: Sorry for not being clear. my last point was meant to clarify that using separate equations was not an option. I thought it would be possible to tinker with eqaution/split/something of the like to achieve the same result.

Comment: on a side note,I had already read  `numbering parentequation of subequations` and favorited it, but was not able to find it out earlier today

Answer (score 5):

You can define a different environment based on `subequations`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\makeatletter
\newenvironment{taggedsubequations}[1]
 {%
  % \end{subequations} will advance `equation`
  \addtocounter{equation}{-1}%
  \begin{subequations}%
  % set the current label
  \def\@currentlabel{#1}%
  % redefine \theequation
  \renewcommand{\theequation}{#1.\arabic{equation}}%
 }
 {\end{subequations}}
\makeatother %not \makeatletter

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
1=1
\end{equation}

\begin{taggedsubequations}{myEQ}\label{eq:w}
\begin{align}
a &= b \label{eq:s1}\\
c &= d \label{eq:s2}
\end{align}
\end{taggedsubequations}

I need to reference \eqref{eq:w} and \eqref{eq:s1} and
would like the tags to be coherent.

\begin{equation}
1=1
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]